# Fingerprint authentication with Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, fingerprint

For a web application, I need to do fingerprint identification and then authenticate with Azure AD. I am familiar with Fingerprint identification and can manage to develop fingerprint identification as a service with C#

After the identification I need to authenticate that user with Azure AD, without entering/passing the password. (Fingerprint only authentication).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. Azure AD will require the password regardless.

In the future we might have a passwordless authentication capability there, but that would be up to the user to enable.

Comment: Thanks Juunas for quick respond. But then do you have any idea about this : https://www.veridiumid.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/AD-Diagram.png

Comment: Where is AAD in that diagram?

Comment: As per the description: https://www.veridiumid.com/biometric-authentication/active-directory-biometrics/, I believe steps 4 goes to Azure AD (The PC icon with Windows Logo)